# What is the best process for adding fields to a mongoose schema which is already storing documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, serverless

I have a Profile schema that already has many documents in the collection and looks something like this:

```js
const Profile = new Schema({
  field_one: String,
  field_two: String
}, { timestamps: true })
```

Now I just added some fields so now the schema looks like this:

```js
const Profile = new Schema({
  field_one: String,
  field_two: String,
  new_field_one: { type: String, default: "Value" },
  new_field_two: { type: String, default: "Value" },
}, { timestamps: true })
```

In my endpoint I see a console log for the object that is being saved which looks like:

```js
const profile = await Profile.create({ ...body })

console.log(body) prints { field_one: "value", field_two: "value", new_field_one: "something", new_field_two: "something" }
```

But new_field_one and new_field_two aren't being stored in the database. I've added the default values and I've add strict false to the Schema but no luck. Is there a way to do this where I don't have to delete all the data in the existing model and rewrite it all to another model then rewrite it to the original model with the new keys?

Answer (score 0):

by default mongo schema use strict option true
so i f you have added new field in scheme it will not reflect on old records
you have to update those records with default values
and on new records it will come as per scheme
us ebelow code to update records

```
Profile.updateMany({}, { $set: { new_field_one: "Value", new_field_two: "Value" } });
```

you can use above code as async also
just use 'await' keyword before query

Comment: The update query is working and I'm seeing the fields on old records, but it still is not storing the values when new records are created

Comment: did you update the schema with new fields, after that i will be storing default value as "Value".  new_field_one: { type: String, default: "Value" },
  new_field_two: { type: String, default: "Value" },